# Входит число в интервал или нет PHP

Tags: php, математика, if

Предположим что у нас есть числа:

Нужно написать условие если $begin и $end хоть как-то задевает интервал от $interval_1 до $interval_2, то вывести "Далее", а если не задевает, то вывести "Ок"

Например:

```
$begin = 660; 
$end = 790;
$interval_1 = 720;
$interval_2 = 760;
```

Вывести: "Далее"

```
$begin = 750; 
$end = 790;
$interval_1 = 720;
$interval_2 = 760;
```

Вывести: "Далее"

```
$begin = 770; 
$end = 790;
$interval_1 = 720;
$interval_2 = 760;
```

Вывести: "Ок"

```
foreach($zhurnal as $key => $value)
{ 
    if(($curret_time + $getTime_uslugi) < $value['begin'] || $curret_time > $value['end'])
    { 
        array_push($times, [
            'begin' => date("H:i", mktime(0, $curret_time, 0)),
            'end' => date("H:i", mktime(0, $curret_time + $getTime_uslugi, 0))
        ]);
        unset($zhurnal[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Можно представить:

```
$curret_time - это begin
($curret_time + $getTime_uslugi) - это $end
$value['begin'] - это $interval_1
$value['end'] - это $interval_2
```

Answer (score 4):

Опираясь на то, что `$begin < $end` и `$interval_1 < $interval_2`, код очень прост:

```
 if ($end < $interval_1 || $begin > $interval_2)
      echo "OK";
 else echo "Далее"
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но реальную задачу все равно не получилось решить...

У меня там есть массив со временем 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [begin] => 660 [end] => 720 ) [1] => Array ( [begin] => 600 [end] => 660 ) )

И этот массив я перебираю с помощью foreach, а внутри уже идет if с вашим условием. Не работает... И я вот не могу понять из-за чего, скорее всего из-за того, что интервалы расположены не по порядку, а в хаотическом порядке

Comment: @webdelo24 возможно, приведите полный код foreach

Comment: добавил код foreach в вопрос